# Vlookup in 2 workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I need to run Vlookups for data in 2 workbooks. I will open both of my workbooks when running the VBA codes, and I saved both workbooks as .xlsm so they are both macro enabled.

I have no problem using the Vlookup Excel function but I want to run it automatically using VBA code.

Here is the information,

I have 2 workbooks, Book3.xlsm and Book32.xlsm. Book3 is where I want my result to be, as shown in the second picture. The data range varies each month, so I need to loop through the end of the last row.

I have 3 columns in Book3 ID and Type and Result and 2 columns in Book32, ID and Result, and I want to do Vlookup using the ID column in Book3 and get the values in Result columns in Book32. The data are both in Sheet1.

Now my code will run but please look for the first picture where it is not showing the desired result. I can leave the value as #N/A if can't be found but in this case, all the values should be found using Vlookup.

Here is my code,

```
Sub test()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim Res_Row As Integer
    Dim Res_Clm As Integer
    Dim Table1 As Range
    Dim Table2 As Range
    Dim cl As Range
    Set Table1 = Workbooks("Book3.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:C")
    Set Table2 = Workbooks("Book32.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:B")
    Res_Row = Sheet1.Range("C2").Row
    Res_Clm = Sheet1.Range("C2").Column
    For Each cl In Table1
        Sheet1.Cells(Res_Row, Res_Clm) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, Table2, 2, False)
        Res_Row = Res_Row + 1
    Next cl

    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I have noticed that vlookup is buggy when values are not [sorted from A-Z](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2016/03/03/excel-vlookup-sorting-problem/) nor [smallest to largest](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/08/27/excel-vlookup-not-working/) and [some other expected stuff](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/04/09/why-excel-vlookup-not-working/), I tend to avoid it as possible because it has caused me trouble in the past and I personally recommend to do an UDF instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this code, which avoids the loop and is easier to read \ maintain.

```
With Workbooks("Book3.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim lRow as Long
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlup).Row

    With .Range("C2:C" & lRow)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=Vlookup(RC[-2],[Book32.xlsm]Sheet1!C1:C2,2,0)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End With
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, when I run the codes, I have a run time error 9 of Subscript out of range and the error is pointing at this line With Workbooks("Book3").Sheets("Sheet1")

Comment: @Johndi - See my edits and try again. Sorry tested after I posted as answer.

Comment: Thanks again, when I run the code, it's giving me a run-time error 1004 now, with Application-Defined or object-defined error and the error is pointing at this line,         .FormulaR1C1 = "=Vlookup(RC[-2],[Book32.xlsm]!Sheet1!C1:C2,2,0)"

Comment: @Johndi - removed the extra `!`. Try again.

Comment: Thank you, it works great now. Can you explain this line?       .FormulaR1C1 = "=Vlookup(RC[-2],[Book32.xlsm]Sheet1!C1:C2,2,0)" my question is I know RC[-2] is the relative position and we are trying to look into Book32 Sheet1 but then with C1:C2, do I need to change the code each month if the range varies?

Comment: @Johndi - Which line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127550/discussion-between-johndi-and-scott-holtzman).

Answer (score 1):

Here it is :

```
Sub test()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim Res_Row As Integer
    Dim Res_Clm As Integer
    Dim Table1 As Range
    Dim Table2 As Range
    Set Table1 = Workbooks("Book3.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:C")
    Set Table2 = Workbooks("Book32.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:B")
    Res_Clm = 3
```

The loop will be on each rows of the table1.

```
    For Each i In Table1.Rows
        If Sheet1.Cells(i.row, 1) = "" Then Exit For
```

If there is no data ("") in the cell, the program exit the loop

```
        Sheet1.Cells(i.row, Res_Clm) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheet1.Cells(i.row, 1), Table2, 2, False)
    Next i
```

Next i increment the i of the for each loop.. It is like i = i+1

```
    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

You use the wrong argument for the first argument of the vlookup.
Also your loop on "cl" would only work on three rows, so I use row argument.

In general, I would adwise to code your vlookup fonction instead of using Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup. I'm quite sure it is longer.

Comment: thank you can you explain these lines and what they do?         If Sheet1.Cells(i.row, 1) = "" Then Exit For
        Sheet1.Cells(i.row, Res_Clm) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheet1.Cells(i.row, 1), Table2, 2, False)
    Next i

Comment: @Johndi I edited the post to explain the line, but I think you should read a basic vba tutorial instead of using the macro recorder.